is there a way in python to automate applications(.exe) for beginner like me?
I would like to automate application programs, from opening the file until automatically working on it. Currently i am learning python and i am using pyautogui & pywinauto, but seems i am having difficulties.
this is an example of what i am working on:
    import os
    import time

    import pyautogui
    import subprocess
#import cv2
#from pywinauto.application import Application
    batLoc = 'D:\program\caller.bat'

    subprocess.Popen(batLoc)

    moveToTaskBar = pyautogui.moveTo(1380, 1150, 0.5)
    pyautogui.click(moveToTaskBar)
    clickExe = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("clickExe.png")
    pyautogui.click(clickExe)
# input correct logincode
#username
    pyautogui.write("00000101")
    pyautogui.hotkey("enter")
#password
    pyautogui.write("101")
    pyautogui.hotkey("enter")
#------script working until here--------
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("clickAdd.png"):
        pyautogui.moveTo(44,44)`your text`
    
#------from above, if statement is not working---`

after opening the application
im done inputing some details on login, it works fine
additional: im calling a batch file which also calls my applications to run.
after logging in, wanted to click buttons inside but I wanted to validate first if the button i wanted to click was there,if so, will click it, else return a message.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
